# Multiple GET or POST variables 404's wordpress pages (numeric permalinks)

Tags: php, wordpress, get, http-status-code-404

I am developing a live-action tag game (called DeTag) that uses a web interface for reporting kills. When a user wants to report a tag they go to a page to confirm who and when they tagged, then actually "kill" them (called pre-tag.php and tag.php respectively).  However in trying both POST and GET data for the three variables I need (userID, tag hour and tag minute,) the page 404's.  Here is the URL that I am using:

```
.../detag/kill?targetID=xxxxxxx&hour=XX&minute=XX
```

That will cause Wordpress (2.1.7) to 404. Tried using both POST and GET data.  However, when I use this link (with only one GET variable):

```
.../detag/kill?targetID=xxxxxxx
```

It works...Of course, it doesn't push the time, but it goes through.  Is there something in PHP and/or Wordpress that would create this situation?

If you need more code, please let me know.

I am using the runphp plugin to run php code on the Wordpress pages.
Thanks.

Comment: Just a matter of curiosity... have you tried using semicolons instead of ampersands to separate the key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our problem was with the type of permalinks we had enabled in WordPress. We changed to the combination enabled links and used semicolons as our variable delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use somethink like this :

```
.../detag/kill?targetID=xxxxxxx[]hour=XX[]minute=XX
```

And in php, use [explode](http://pt.php.net/explode) function to get the parameters.